# How to get all web controls on a sharepoint page

Tags: 2007, development

I need to get all web controls on a SharePoint page but not sure,

```
using (SPSite bigSite = new SPSite("http://bigPortal.bbbb.com/bb/bbWeb"))
            using (SPWeb bigWeb = bigSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                foreach(WebControl wc in bigWeb  //not sure what will go here
            }
```

I need all buttons, all gridviews, all labels, all textboxes

Answer (score 2):

First of you need to get hold of the page and not just the web object. Like this:

```
page = web.GetObject(pageUrl) as SPListItem;
```

But even then it would be tricky to get all controls. What is your objective? Maybee there is a better way of establishing what you want

Comment: My Objective is to get all controls on the page, again and again and again

Comment: You made that clear ;) what I am asking is why

Comment: Because it makes me feel good, thats why ;)

Comment: Added code for getting the listitem of the page if that helps..

Comment: I cannot get web controls using page control otherwise I would use SPFile instead to get page.

Comment: Well exactly, and I think there is really no other way to do it, webparts is one thing, but not all controls

Comment: I might wait for Steve blamer to come across my question one day and add some functionality then, thank you

Comment: Hehe, we could only wish it was as easy as in normal asp.net application with the Page.Controls method :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 //method that will be getting the controls 
    using (SPSite bigSite = new SPSite("http://bigPortal.bbbb.com/bb/bbWeb"))
    {
        using (SPWeb bigWeb = bigSite.OpenWeb())
        {
             GetControlsRecursively(Page.Controls);
        }
    }


//the list that will store the controls
private IList<Control> _controlsList = new List<Control>();

//get controls that calls a method to iterate through parent and child controls
public IEnumerable<Control> GetControlsRecursively(Control container)
{
     _controlsList.Clear();
     getParentChildcontrol(container);

     return _controlsList;
}

//recursive method to get child controls from parent if it exists and adds to the list
private void getParentChildcontrol(Control container)
{
   foreach (Control control in container.Controls)
   {
       _controlsList.Add(control);
       if (container.HasChildren)
       {
            getParentChildcontrol(control);
       }
   }
}
```

it needs some changing but you can get the gist of it from this! needs some ammendments!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4.aspx

link above is simple and works well but if a control is within a container than it will not show up! as an example you have a textbox within a panel than it will show the panel control but not the textbox! what you need to do is get the last part of my code and add it in to loop through each child control ;)

forgot to mention to have this in a webpart so you can do Page.Control ;)

Comment: console application where i need it not into a webpart, in colsoe application it cannot find FindControlsRecursively, i not know why not

Comment: sorry was a typo! just ammended the code it was ment to call the function below it! it should work now! I was just giving you a webpart as an example